# download page based on javascript with php

Tags: javascript, php, curl, download, html

I need to download web page that is based on javascript. Other pages I download with curl, but when I try it on this site it writes only that javascript is required and does not show any content. I tried also file_get_contents, but it is not working too.
Is there any posibility how to download site which is checking if javascript is enabled?
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Can we access that web page to check how they see if JS is on or off?

Comment: it is www.seznam.sk, I need to check position of web page for seo there.